# C# How to fit my window dimensions to my string text

Tags: wpf, string, line

So i have small `Form` with 2 `Labels`: `Caption` and `Message` and Ok `button`:

Suppose I have a string with the text:

> "Cable News Network is an American basic cable and satellite
>   television news channel owned by the Turner Broadcasting System, a
>   division of Time Warner. CNN was founded in 1980 by American media
>   proprietor Ted Turner as a 24-hour cable news channe"

Now this string should put inside `Label` in order to see in in a small window just like `Message Box` window.

This is my `Form':

```
<Border Background="Red" BorderBrush="#FF103766" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="20,20,20,20">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="110"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="IndianRed" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Name="lblCaption"
                   FontSize="20"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="Yellow"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </Border>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Label Name="lblMessage"                          
                   FontSize="15"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
            <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="IndianRed" Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Name="btnOk"
                        Content="OK"
                        FontSize="16"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Click="btnOk_Click""/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

How can i automatically fit this `Grid` dimensions to my `Label` that contains my `Text` ?

**EDIT**

I also want to break the message line to fit the with

Comment: Just to be sure: is this WPF?

Comment: In the window that shows your usercontrol just set  SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"

Comment: Yes WPF, i just edit my Label and my message

Comment: user @taquion: where i need to do that ?

Comment: @DeetGlol see the answer, you can set it also in code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set **SizeToContent** to proper value in the window that shows your user control:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In this case **MyUserControl** is your Form

Comment: And what about bear the message to new line to fit to the windows with ?

Comment: In that case you need to use a TextBlock instead and set its TextWrapping property: <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

Comment: If you still want to use the label then you need to provide a nested textblock as content... XD

Comment: OK this looks fine now with the textblock but if i want a little space in the sides ? currently the message is take place for all the with without any space on the sides

Comment: Then set Margin in your textblock: <TextBlock Margin = "10">